# Will jwts reduce performance and not improve anything in this case?

Tags: php, c++, mysql, jwt

as title says I'm asking if JWTs are a good addition or if they are not needed or better not used in this case. I already read A LOT of information and still couldn't come with a complete answer.

**I'm taking into account the following things:**

1. Security.
2. Speed / Response Time / Performance.
3. Resources used in the server (CPU, RAM, etc.).
4. Disabled multilogin (No more than 1 client per account).

**My situation Client-Side:**

- Desktop app written in C++ that requires constant internet connection.
- 1 Time login when opening the app and then a Request every X seconds telling the server that the user is still using the app. (because the app might crash and the server wouldn't know that the user is not using the app anymore).
- Browser is NEVER used.

**My situation Server-Side:**

- Low resource Cloud Hosting.
- Login API that handles authentication. (PHP and MySQL)
- Check API that handles those requests every X seconds. (PHP and MySQL)
- Around 50-70 users.

**How I'm doing it right now:**

- First: User logs in, a Token is created using random_bytes(), stored in the db and sent to the client. (check code below)
- Second: The client sends user, pw and token every X seconds.
- Third: Server checks that the token is valid for that user and lets the user continue to use the app until the next check.
- Fourth: After x+5 seconds of no requests from the user, the token expires.

For "First" and "Second" I'm using:

```php
<?php
.
.
.
$token = bin2hex(random_bytes(32));
$stmt = $con->prepare("UPDATE accounts_table SET loggedin = 1, token = ? WHERE Username = ?");
$stmt->bind_param('ss', $token, $username);
$stmt->execute();
echo $token;
?>
```

For "Third" I'm using:

```php
<?php
.
.
.
$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM accounts_table WHERE username= ? LIMIT 1");
$stmt->bind_param('s', $user);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
$result = $result->fetch_array();
if ($token==$result['token'])
  {in pseudo-code} tell the client that everything is ok
else
  {in pseudo-code} tell the client that he is not allowed to use the app anymore.
?>
```

**About the things I wrote before.**

1. Security

From what I read from a lot of answers in StackExchange and StackOverflow JWTs are safe as long as the private key is not stolen. If there is something I missed please tell me.

2. Speed / Response Time / Performance and 3. Resources used in the server (CPU, RAM, etc.)

From what I read in articles about JWTs (Like this one for example: [Why jwts suck as session tokens](https://scotch.io/bar-talk/why-jwts-suck-as-session-tokens#toc-why-do-jwts-suck-)), they will increase the size of the requests, and also increase the resources (CPU, RAM, etc.) needed on every request since it has to compute hashes. Also I read this about HTTP/2 [hpack the silent killer feature of http](https://blog.cloudflare.com/hpack-the-silent-killer-feature-of-http-2/) which shows that the increased size doesn't matter because of the compression.

But still I'm concerned about the increased resource usage, will the performance impact be perceptible? I have to ask this because I don't know a way to reproduce a situation of 50 users using the app at the same time.

4. Disabled multilogin (No more than 1 client per account).

Since login checks if user is not logged in using "loggedin" flag, it won't allow multilogin. If you find a flaw please tell me.

5. Extra: Is there any better approach?

I read about sessions as well, but is it needed? Will it improve my situation or it will be the same?

Thanks in advance.